# May I use Bootstrap-CDN on Subtheme for production site?

Tags: 7, cdn, theming

Follow up of my other question with less files ;-)

As I don't need de less files on production site, could I then switch to BootstrapCDN for js files? Or would it overrule style.css too?

Thx for your support guys!!

Comment: You can go with bootstrapcdn.

Comment: If you are on Drupal 8, I suggest the Radix theme (and corresponding subtheme) for Bootstrap 4 support: https://www.drupal.org/project/radix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the BoostrapCDN for js and your own style.css. I'm not sure if would overwrite but if those you can create a separate file that is not style.css on the info file to add your CSS or your JavaScript.

If you are using the [Bootstrap project](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) by default it allow you to use the CDN.